# Which package gives diacritics for commands like {\b b}

Tags: symbols, packages

Which package gives this output

[image: output {\b b} {\c c} {\u u}]

with this input `\b{b} \c{c} \u{u}`?

Is there a tabulation of these possibilities that you would point to?

Comment: there are already defined in latex, and you find them e.g. in encguide.pdf (`texdoc encguide`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. This is an answer, please convert to answer.

Comment: The syntax should be `\b{b} \c{c} \u{u}`. If you use the characters in `.bib` files, though, then it should be `{\b{b}}` and similarly for the others.

Answer (score 2):

*[Just repeating the comments from Ulrike Fischer and egreg, because after 2.5 years there was still no answer to the question; marked as community wiki:]*

They are already defined in LaTeX, and you find them e.g. in encguide.pdf (`texdoc encguide` or at https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf).

The syntax should be `\b{b} \c{c} \u{u}`. If you use the characters in `.bib` files, though, then it should be `{\b{b}}` and similarly for the others.

Additionally, with current, unicode-aware LaTeX-engines, you can also write `ḇ ç ŭ`. While XeLaTeX compiles all three, LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX only understand the `ç ŭ`.